# How can I tell clang-format to indent visibility modifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang-format

I want my visibility modifiers (`public`, `protected` and `private`) to be indented by clang-format who currently leaves them at the same level as the class declaration. I've looked for `indent` and `visibility` on a dump of the default format options but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [Clang-Format Style Options documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> AccessModifierOffset (int)
>   The extra indent or outdent of access modifiers, e.g. public:.

So, add the appropriate entry to your `.clang-format`. For example,

```
AccessModifierOffset: 2
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the code following them indented accordingly? Just using this only indents the modifier and the following code does not follow?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to give the access modifiers themselves their own level of indentation, you can use `IndentAccessModifiers: true`.  This will give you code that looks like the following.

```
class my_class {
  public:
    my_class() = default;
};
```

With `IndentAccessModifiers: false`, by default you'll get the access modifiers not indented at all, and class members will be indented only one level beyond the surrounding scope.

```
class my_class {
public:
  my_class() = default;
};
```

You can then use `AccessModifierOffset` to adjust the alignment of the access modifiers only, without affecting the alignment of the class members.  With `IndentAccessModifiers: false` and `AccessModifierOffset: 1`, you'd get this.

```
class my_class {
 public:
  my_class() = default;
};
```

With `IndentAccessModifiers: true`, `AccessModifierOffset` is ignored.

I'm sure all reasonable programmers would agree that only one of these options is even remotely acceptable.  Though they probably wouldn't agree on which one it is.

Comment: I just discovered to my dismay that `IndentAccessModifiers` is not yet in a released version of ClangFormat.  Hopefully this answer will at least be useful in the future once Clang 12 is released (or to those with from-source Clang installations now).

Comment: For the second demo, AccessModifierOffset should be -1?