# clang-format Class Ident Access Modifiers

Tags: c, header, llvm, clang-format

I'm trying format one c header file. While `struct` idents is equals to `class variables.`

test.h:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        int var;
        int var2;
}

struct myst {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};
```

Style Config:

```
TabWidth: 4
IndentWidth: 4
UseTab: Always
IndentAccessModifiers: true
```

Run:

```
clang-format -style="{TabWidth: 4, IndentWidth: 4, UseTab: Always, IndentAccessModifiers: true}" test.h
```

The following output is bad. (in `struct` is must be one tab not more!)

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        int var;
        int var2;
}

struct myst {
        int foo;
        int bar;
};
```

Also like this output:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        int var;
        int var2;
}

struct myst {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Follwing [Sam Marinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5017858/sam-marinelli)'s  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66998211/10961502)

According to the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#indentaccessmodifiers) using `IndentAccessModifiers` will result in record members always being indented two levels. It's currently not possible to indent in two different use-cases (with and without access modifiers)

What you can do is change the indentation of the access modifiers themselves.

Looking at your target output we have the following:

- Your base offset is 6. This will result in `IndentWidth: 6`
- Your modifiers are offset as 4, so we will use a negative offset to unindent them, resulting in `AccessModifierOffset: -2`
- `AccessModifierOffset` is ignored when `IndentAccessModifiers` is used. So we need to remove that line or set it to `false`.

All together this will result in the following:

Style Config:

```
AccessModifierOffset: -2
TabWidth: 4
IndentWidth: 6
UseTab: Always
IndentAccessModifiers: false
```

Output:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
      int var;
      int var2;
}

struct myst {
      int foo;
      int bar;
};
```

As an alternative you can also use `IndentWidth: 4` to get this result:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    int var;
    int var2;
}

struct myst {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};
```